# .htaccess: Redirect and add parameter if URL contains a specific parameter

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a URL to which external partners might be appending utm parameters (utm_source, utm_medium...) and I have no control over this. If a URL contains the utm_source parameter I need to redirect to the same URL, but appending a further parameter which contains the value of utm_source

So, if the URL contains the utm_source parameter:
https://example.com/path/index.htm?utm_source=abc&utm_medium=123

Redirect it to:
https://example.com/path/index.htm?utm_source=abc&utm_medium=123&source=abc

Note 1: the value of both utm_source and source is the same

Note 2: no redirection for:
https://example.com/path/index.htm

This is what I've tried, but it does not work:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(utm_source=(.*).+)$  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1%1&source=%2 [L]
```

How do I do this using .htaccess?

**EDIT**
The closest I've got is this thanks to @Don'tPanic

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)utm_source=([^&]*)(.*)$
RewriteRule (.*)intro.htm $1intro.htm?%1utm_source=%2&source=%2%3 [R,END]
```

This however sends the redirect in an endless loop.
How can I execute this only once?

Comment: What have you tried? I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4887749/append-a-parameter-to-a-querystring-with-mod-rewrite) which shows how to test the content of the query string, which seems to be the first half of your problem. I then found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74015970/replacing-one-of-the-parameters-in-the-url-having-a-query-string-and-retaining-t) which shows how to use the *value* of a query string parameter ... seems like you could hack together something from those examples?  Have you tried anything like that yet?

Comment: @Don'tPanic Thank you for sharing this. Unfortunately it doesn't help me. The URL and the query string are not fixed and I'm not sure how to build this

Comment: You are getting an endless loop because you're doing an external redirect by specifying the `R` flag.  [The `END` flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_end) terminates redirects but only for the current request - `R` issues a new request so `END` has no effect here.  Your previous example didn't include that so I assumed that's not what you were after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fired up a Docker container and played around with this.  The [Apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/remapping.html#rewrite-query) give some tips, and some experimenting led me to a simplified version of their examples:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)utm_source=([^&]*)(.*)
RewriteRule index.php /index.php?%1utm_source=%2&source=%2%3 [END]
```

The condition checks the query string for:

- anything in the string before `utm_source`, and captures it as `%1`;
- the value of the `utm_string`, and captures it as %2;
- anything in the string after the `utm_source` value, and captures it as `%3`;

Then redirects, preserving the components of the query string, and inserting `source=` with the value of whatever `utm_source` was.

This works for me, if `index.php` just dumps out `$_GET`, for test URLs everyrhing works as expected:

```
http://localhost/index.php?utm_source=stackoverflow
Array
(
    [utm_source] => stackoverflow
    [source] => stackoverflow
)

http://localhost/index.php?a=foo&utm_source=so
Array
(
    [a] => foo
    [utm_source] => so
    [source] => so
)

http://localhost/index.php?a=foo&utm_source=so&b=bar
Array
(
    [a] => foo
    [utm_source] => so
    [source] => so
    [b] => bar
)
```

**EDIT**

To redirect all URLs, not just `index.php` (or `.html`), just change the rewrite rule to match anything, capture the match, and redirect to it:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1utm_source=%2&source=%2%3 [END]
```

**EDIT 2**

If you want to do an *external* redirect, which means you really make 2 requests to Apache and end up with a different URL in the browser, you open up a whole new can of worms:

- Since it is a completely new request, the redirect rules are applied again, for the new request.  `END` has no effect, because that [terminates processing for the current request](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_end) - it doesn't affect a new request.
- Likewise the more commonly used `L` flag, it doesn't affect a new request.
- You could try checking that `source` does not exist in the URL yet, meaning this is the *first* request ... except `source` appears in `utm_source`, so that will never be true.
- You could try checking for a word-break character before `source` to match it but not `utm_source` ... but the `_` in `utm_source` would also match that;
- There is a `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment flag which is set after the first *internal* redirect ... but that's *internal*, and you're now doing *external*.
- You can [set environment flags](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/advanced.html#setenvvars) to track status in a request ... but they won't be around in a new request.

All I can think of is to make sure the string `utm_source=..&source=...` does not exist.  This doesn't feel like a good solution to me as it relies on the order of the parameters in the URL, but it works:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)utm_source=([^&]*)(.*)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !utm_source=([^&]*)&source=\1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1utm_source=%2&source=%2%3 [R,L]
```

Questions I used to get here:

- [Append a parameter to a querystring with mod_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4887749/append-a-parameter-to-a-querystring-with-mod-rewrite)
- [How can I get mod_rewrite to match a rule just once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6342261/how-can-i-get-mod-rewrite-to-match-a-rule-just-once)

Comment: Thank you very much. For my understanding this should work exactly as I need, but somehow it does not. I tried both locally and on my server, but there is no redirection (and no appending of the source parameter.

Comment: Additionally, do you know how to modify this for it to work with any URL path?

Comment: I went through the links - especially the Apache docs: it should work! No idea why not. Let me check

Comment: I updated the answer to show how to redirect everything.

Comment: And I've updated to show a solution for external redirects.

Comment: This is brilliant, thank you! It solved my problem. The key was the second RewriteCond to which I had not thought about. Thank you very much!